# Maximum Likelihood Estimation is increasing the Variance instead of learning something useful from the data

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, fitting

I have a simple neural network $\tau(x)=[\mu(x), \sigma(x)]$ to model the following distribution:$$
\hat y = \mathcal N(\mu(x),\text{Softplus}(\sigma(x)))
$$
However, instead of learning something useful in the data, the network $\tau$ instead **increases** the expected value of $\sigma(x)$ which does maximize the log likelihood.

In other words, the network learns the data as noise. This issue is fixed  if I let $\sigma(x)=c$, a constant that I manually tune. However, this will add additional biases to the model and I want to learn the variance from the data as well.

I have tried using a Sigmoid activation multiplied to a large constant:
$$
\text{Sigmoid}(x)\cdot k
$$ where $k=\mathbb E[y] / 3$ to limit the possible variance of the model but this suffers from numerical instabilities. Please help me, **'What to do when the model learns the data as noise when minimizing the NLL?'**

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (toy data?) And the code for implementation ( keras?  Tensorflow probability? )

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg it would be difficult to include since it is a custom Variational Diffusion Model operating in the latent space. My **decoder network** to reconstruct the image from the latent space has a Quantized Gaussian likelihood as mentioned above and it is prioritizing maximizing the variance to minimize the reconstruction loss (NLL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to look at "Optimal Training of Mean Variance Estimation Neural Networks" by Sluijterman, Cator, and Heskes
(https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08875) .  Just got posted last week on exactly this problem and strategies to avoid it.

Tl;Dr:

- Use a warmup period to train mean first, and once mean converged, then train variance
- Use different subnetworks and regularization parameters for each parameter of the distribution.  That way network can actually learn different feature mappings for each output neuron; if you simply use a fully connected DNN with just the last layer as 2 output neurons , you don't leave enough freedom for network to explore the functional space independently between mean and variance.

Comment: Regularization currently did not work so I will read and try the suggested method. Thank you

Comment: @wdviolet Any success with the two step estimation procedure?

Comment: I apologize for not coming back to you sooner. What I did is fix a small non learnable variance to train and initialize the mean parameters. I then trained both the mean and variance simultaneously but I achieve only average acceptable results. What I did is reduce the learning rate particularly for the variance parameters and this led to a much better generation samples. I also applied separate heads or neural networks for the mean and variance instead of splitting the features of a single network.

Comment: The extra procedure I've done might be because of the complicated structure of a latent diffusion model with both reconstruction and diffusion (KL) loss. I tried this method earlier on a simple regression problem with an l-2 penalty and the procedure you stated works all of the time since the weights converges to the same value.